# php shell_exec iwgetid ignores quotes

Tags: php, shell-exec, iwconfig

I am trying to get the SSID from a Linux machine with PHP, but with shell_exec values between quotes seem to be ignored.

In the cli the result of iwgetid is:

```
wlan0     ESSID:"test"
```

However if I do the same with PHP using shell_exec:

```
$ssidInfo = shell_exec("iwgetid");
```

I get the following result:

```
wlan0     ESSID:
```

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: I think `iwgetid` has to be run by root. What user is running the PHP script?

Comment: When you tried it in the CLI, were you running as root? Does it work in the CLI as an ordinary user?

Comment: When I change user to www-data in cli it still seems to work: sudo su - www-data
$ iwgetid
wlan0     ESSID:"test"

Comment: How are you displaying `$ssidInfo`?

Comment: The web page I found that said it required root was 5 years old, it may have changed since then.

Comment: "How are you displaying $ssidInfo?" This was the golden pointer, my framework view seems to filter it away, when I simply echo it is there. Thank you for your assistance :)